# What is the entry point of Python program of multiple modules?

Tags: python, sequence, execution

I want to understand from which point a Python program starts running. I have previous experience in `Java`. In `Java` every program starts from `main()` function of it's `Main` class. Knowing this I can determine the execution sequence of other classes or functions of other Classes. I know that in Python I can control program execution sequence by using `__name__` like this:

```
def main():
    print("This is the main routine.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when we don't use `__name__` then what is the starting line of my Python program?

Comment: by default the starting line is always the first line, just keep in mind that functions don't call themselves.

Comment: Python programs start executing at the beginning of the file, and code is executed line-by-line. Any imports will execute the entire imported file (and any files imported in that file etc etc)

Comment: But when I have multiple modules then first line of which module will run at first? Is it randomly selected?

Comment: Note, the `__name__` idiom is to *guard* against executing code when the file is not the primary file run by the interpreter, i.e. `python some_file`.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam no, it is the module you *start yourself* with `python some_module`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah, it makes sense :)

Comment: Note, this is exactly how the JVM interpreter works, when you do `java SomeCompiledClass` except in Java, there *must* be a `main` method. that serves as the entry-point. In Python, it just runs top-to-bottom

Comment: So if I want to control a program like Java then I should create a module as my Main class (say "main"). Then I shall import other modules and functions inside this main module. And I shall run python main.py. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but it's a module, not a class. But again, that's also how Java works. The only difference is the entry point into that file. And the fact that Python will execute all the source-code in a module, hence the use of `__name__ == '__main__'` to guard against executing code you might want to place inside a module but only want to execute it if it is the "main" module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Interpreter starts to interpret file line by line from the beginning.
>   If it encounters function definition, it adds it into the **globals**
>   dict. If it encounters function call, it searches it in **globals**
>   dict and executes or fail.

```
# foo.py
def foo():
    print "hello"
foo()

def test()
    print "test"

print "global_string"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "executed"
else:
    print "imported"
```

**Output**

```
hello
global_string
executed
```

- Interpreter starts to interpret foo.py line by line from the beginning like first the function definition it adds to globals dict and then it encounters the call to the function `foo()` and execute it so it prints `hello`.
- After that, it adds `test()` to global dict but there's no function call to this function so it will not execute the function.
- After that print statement will execute will print `global_string`.
- After that, if condition will execute and in this case, it matched and will print `executed`.